# What do cumulonimbus clouds signify?

Tags: atmosphere

When I saw huge cumulonimbus clouds in the sky I thought the weather would be just fine, but in the evening it started raining. So I just wanted to know what do these clouds really signify.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. "Cumulonimbus" is from "cumulus" (Latin for "heap") and "nimbus" (Latin for "rainstorm" or "storm cloud"). So, what happened isn't that surprising. You might want to do some research on the different cloud types, which is probably too broad for this format.

Comment: "the different cloud types" is certainly too broad, but I can imagine a good answer explaining what happens in a cumulonimbus and how this is associated with bad weather.

Comment: This is an uncommonly simple quesiton, and it is interesting that Wikipedia does not contain the simple diagram that in included in the answer to this question. It's what i learned in school in geography when i was 15. There is a wiki version of the diagram but i cant be bothered to edit the wikipedia page to add what i learnt at 15 in a standard textbook. https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/01/Example_of_a_cold_front.svg/320px-Example_of_a_cold_front.svg.png

Answer (score 1):

Cumulonimbus clouds are thunder clouds, they are heavy and dense clouds that come in large heaps, these clouds produce precipitation or rain, Cumulonimbus clouds also produce hail and tornadoes.

Answer (score 0):

Cumulonimbus clouds are very high clouds with large amounts of water vapor rising 5-10 kilometers in altitude and they often flatten whey they reach higher than 10km kilometers. Their upper limit is 12.2 kilometers.

They from when cold air front arrives in a hot area and sends the hot air with moisture very high up and very forcefully, where it cools and becomes huge clouds. [image]